# javascript checkbox/uncheckbox multiple items in same div

Tags: javascript, html

If I have options with checkboxes like this,
[imag1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMgsU.jpg)

I need to know if there is any way in javascript which allows me to do:
If I check traumatic, then check non traumatic, then traumatic should be unchecked automatically. Same with the next 2 options. If I check acute, then check chronic automatically, then acute should be unchecked.I should be able to select 2 options also from them- like acute and traumatic or chronic and non-traumatic and so on. All these options are present in the same input id and div. The code to display them is something like this:

```
if(final_comorb != null && final_comorb.length != 0) {
            for(var i=0; i<final_comorb.length; i++) {
                tableBody += "<tr><td><table>"
                          + "<tr onmouseover=\"mouseOverPara('rrSentencesImg"+index+impression_prefix+i+"','rrSentencesCol"+index+impression_prefix+i+"');\" onmouseout=\"mouseOutPara('rrSentencesImg"+index+impression_prefix+i+"','rrSentencesCol"+index+impression_prefix+i+"');\">"
                          + "<td><div id='rrSentencesCol"+index+impression_prefix+i+"'>"
                          + "<a onmouseover=\"makeDivVisibleRR('rrSentences"+index+impression_prefix+i+"');\" onmouseout=\"makeDivHiddenRR('rrSentences"+index+impression_prefix+i+"');\">"
                          + "<b><font color='#0000FF'><input class='rrPart' id='rrGroup"+index+impression_prefix+i+"' type='checkbox' value='GROUP' onclick='javascript:otherForm(\"rrChkGrp"+index+impression_prefix+i+"\",\"rrGroup"+index+impression_prefix+i+"\");'>"+final_comorb[i][1]
                          + "</font></b></a></div>";

                tableBody += "<div id='rrChkGrp"+index+impression_prefix+i+"' style='display: none; margin-left: 60px;'>";

                for(var j=2; j<final_comorb[i].length; j++) {
                    for(var k=0;k<final_comorb[i][j].length;k++){
                    tableBody += "<br><input class='rrPart"+index+impression_prefix+i+"' id='rrGrp"+index+impression_prefix+i+"Chk"+j+"' type='checkbox'>"+final_comorb[i][j][k];
                    }
                }
}
}
```

The 7th line(final_comorb[i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMgsU.jpg)) displays the first level term, in this example Subdural. The 14th line final_comorb[i][j][k] displays these above mentioned options. How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like you should be using radio buttons.

Comment: the design needs checkboxes only. Is there any way this can be implemented with checkboxes?

Comment: this can be done in a couple ways, you could style radio buttons to look like checkboxes or using jQuery this is not to hard, vanilla JS makes it tough, are you open to either of those options?

Comment: share your rendered html content

Comment: Sure I can try both options @Omarjmh Can I know how can this be done?

Comment: I am getting the same output as in the image right now @Arun P Johny. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to keep checkboxes, see if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ramanbedi1989/t5w19o3m/1/) fiddle can help.

```
$(function(){
  var checkboxBinding = {};
  $('[data-binding]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var bindingName = $this.data('binding');
    if(checkboxBinding[bindingName] === undefined){
      checkboxBinding[bindingName] = [];
    }
    checkboxBinding[bindingName].push($this);
    $this.on('change', function(){
      if($this.is(':checked')){
        var bindingsArr = checkboxBinding[bindingName];
        bindingsArr.forEach(function(checkboxItem){
          if(checkboxItem !== $this){
            $(checkboxItem).prop('checked', false);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey this answer is amazing! Thanks a lot. One query- in the fiddle you have used data-binding="traumatic-non-traumatic" etc, right. But these values might not always be the same. It depends on what is the value obtained in the final_comorb array, which is different on different runs of the program. Is there any way to make it dynamic?

Comment: Its dynamic currently as well, just be sure to make `data-binding` value to be same for the checkboxes that you want to combine. And please mark the answer as accepted if it has helped you.

Comment: hey by making 'data binding value same', do you mean something like this - final_comorb[0][0][0] and final_comorb[0][0][1] should have same data binding values? Because I look through the array in the for loops as in the code.

Comment: When the array populates, my final_comorb[0][0][0] will have traumatic, final_comorb[0][0][1] will have non-tarumatic and so on...

Comment: can you by any way determine which two checkboxes will be binded together? e.g. determining that `traumatic` and `non-traumatic` are binded in a way that when one is checked then the other is unchecked.

Comment: you just need to keep `data-binding` attribute of your checkbox equal to the other checkbox's `data-binding` attribute so that the code can determine what all checkboxes have to be unchecked when one of them is checked.

Comment: No the values are dynamic. These values are obtained by some other processing of a very large database. And the values I get in the final_comorb array are different everytime I run the program. The above traumatic -non traumatic case is just one case among the many.

Comment: the thing is I don't know what value is should use for the data-binding column in the following line -                                                      tableBody += "<br><input class='rrPart"+index+impression_prefix+i+"' id='rrGrp"+index+impression_prefix+i+"Chk"+j+"' type='checkbox' data-binding="   ">"+final_comorb[i][j][k];

Comment: Vinay, my point is that you can keep any value in `data-binding` attribute. Just keep this value the same for the checkboxes that need to be binded together.

Comment: Hey I got that. But the thing is I do not know which indexes are what to bind the categories together. I will know them after I get the output. I know the checkboxes that can be together. But there is no way to know that final_comorb[0][0][0] will be traumatic always . I may not have these options for subcategories in some other run of the program. I may have some other categories altogether. Can you please elaborate and help me out on this? Thanks.

Comment: Vinay your code also needs to know what checkboxes are to be binded together. Once you can determine that, you can even keep the value of `data-binding` equal to `final_comorb[0][0][0] + final_comorb[0][0][1]` as well

Comment: Oh ok. So I should now a list of categories that can be combined together and those that cannot be combined together to employ this method right?

Comment: sure, do let me know if you get a problem

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way, to style the radio buttons, which have the default functionality you are asking for INTO checkboxes:

**HTML:**

```
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> traumatic</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> non traumatic 2</label>

<div></div>

<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> acute</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> chronic 2</label>
```

- I only put that div in there to kick the inputs to the next row

**CSS**

```
input[type="radio"] {
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox; 
    -moz-appearance: checkbox;    
}
```

[Example working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omarjmh/6po26fkw/1/)

Comment: you can now add some styles to clean it up... good luck, interesting question!

Comment: Hey this is a good answer. Thanks for the help. But there is another problem. The thing is I want to select 2 options out of the 5 at the same time, which radio buttons do not allow. The combinations that can be selected together are - Acute and traumatic, acute and non-traumatic, chronic and traumatic, chronic and non-traumatic. The selections that should not be possible together are just 2- acute and chronic, traumatic and non-traumatic. So,if I check acute first and chronic later, then acute should get unchecked automatically. This multiple selections is not possible with radio buttons.

Comment: well then you need to do something like that, then try the answer from @Raman, but since he beat me to it, I wont try to snipe his karma and give you essentially the same thing...